# Sublime Text Code Editor + Blender (How Can I use a External Editor instead of Blender?)

Tags: python

I trying edit the python script archive through Sublime Text Editor instead through Blender Native Editor, because it give not a good support how Sublime Text Editor gives me.

I just want do this, when i edit the code through Sublime Text Editor the Blender detect that has one change in the same archive but not make nothing in script inside of blender editor without i need to click in warning button to refresh the code.

Somebody can give me a solution without need to develop so much code?(I want not be a Blender developer or study very much the Blender)